# Fields empty in Reporting Services report Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have created a report with a quite complex SQL query but relatively simple layout.

It's just a table with many fields, the preview in Visual Studio is perfectly OK, but in the Report Manager application in my browser many fields are shown as simply "empty".

I have inspected the HTML of the generated report, some table cells have a TD element, with an inner DIV with the expected values...

Somes simply have a TD element with nothing in it.

See a preview here: http://it.tinypic.com/r/2w69qvt/9

Comment: Check the data source in the report properties in report manager. It may not be the same as the one in VS.

Comment: thanks, I will check it...but if the DS were different I would get some kind of error, right?

Comment: It's usually a case of looking at development data as opposed to production.

Comment: data are the same. backup/restore done ad the query returns exacly the same # of rows and same data

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
StevenWhite pointed me in the right direction. 
DataSource was OK but Dataset definition was probably not aligned with the one on my development machine.